# Why is the voltage across the LED negative, when the entire drop is positive?

Tags: voltage, led, voltage-measurement

I was changing the control board of my 3D printer. When testing the heatbed, I saw that the LED wasn't glowing (as with the old control board), when the heatbed was turned on. So I investigated with my multimeter.

The circuit is pretty simple (taken from the [prusa3d GitHub](https://github.com/prusa3d/Heatbed_MK52_magnetic), the wire on the right stands for the heating loops on the PCB).

[image]

So more appropriately would be:

[image]

Here my observations (during a long period, so there should be no PWM):

1. The heatbed warms up in a timely manner
2. Measured the voltage drop between the contacts (VCC to GND: 11.36 V) [image]
3. Measured the voltage drop across R1 (VCC 10.36 V to pad of R1 towards D1)
4. Measured the voltage drop across D1 (-2 V, both pads of the diode, however the value varies) [image]
5. I checked the function of the diode with the diode setting on the multimeter

I understand that the diode won't glow with a negative voltage, but why is the measured voltage negative?

Comment: The circuit makes no sense. VCC is shorted directly to GND. Are you sure you are measuring drops in correct way, and it would help to know with what you are measuring and how, and are the multimeter batteries dead if you are using a multimeter.

Comment: Hi @Justme, the circuit is taken from the prusa github. The wire on the right is the "heating" part, one can see it nicely in the image from Prusa https://raw.githubusercontent.com/prusa3d/Heatbed_MK52_magnetic/master/12V_05e/Heatbed-MK52.png

I also added the information where I measured the voltages

Comment: Then the heater should be shown as a resistor. If it doesn't have resistance then it can't dissipate power and won't generate heat!

Comment: Are you being consistent with your multimeter lead orientation? The V+ lead (red - if they're plugged in correctly) should always be to the top of the component being measured on your diagram. If you swapped the leads then that would explain your problem.

Comment: @Transistor Yes, I am

Comment: @JoeyD OK so the schematic is not yours and it is drawn wrong because it contains a short circuit Please add proper attribution to the image into the question. Also the measurements cannot be true because they do not add up. If you measure 11. 36V between VCC and GND, and 10.36V over the resistor, it means there must be exactly 1.00V left over for the LED.

Comment: @Justme as I said, which is why i am stumped. Also as I observed, the LED isn't glowing. I am more than willing to learn here, what I did wrong

Comment: Which multimeter you have, how are the leads connected, and what settings are used on the multimeter? So basically, you are trying to measure why the LED does not light up?

Comment: @Justme It's a Voltcraft VC140 from Conrad. And yes to your question

Comment: @Justme the schematic is not really drawn wrong, 3D printers use a long labyrinthine PCB trace as a large flat heating element so it is literally a short circuit, however it's a very long trace of a known resistance. The LED is placed across this.

Comment: @JohnU, "*so it is literally a short circuit*". No it's not. It's a low value resistor. There's 12 V across it which would be impossible with a short-circuit. Maybe "literally" means something else to you? :^)

Comment: @JohnU That is debateable whether that is not really wrong, or just wrong, unvonventional, bad, or the best way ever to draw it. The schematics do not convey that information that it is a PCB trace heating element, and there is no such schematic symbol or comment in the schematics. All it shows is a direct short between supply and ground, and whether it really isn't is left for imagination.

Comment: @JoeyD You measured the LED in diode mode? What was the result? Did you measure the resistance of resistor? Is the resistor broken, or some PCB track on the path of the LED?

Comment: @Justme Sorry for answering that late, family took priority :-) I measured the LED and it glowed... however, i now was able to "fix" my issue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your circuit was broken if the resistor was badly mounted and made no contact.

It means the LED anode was not connected anywhere, and LED cathode was connected to negative supply lead.

LEDs are light emitting diodes when power is applied, but they also work in reverse, acting as photodiodes or solar cells, only they are not very good at it as they are optimized for light emission.

So, in short, there was light shining on the LED, it was not connected anywhere, and the photovoltaic effect made voltage appear on LED termnals, which you were able to measure with a multimeter.

The polarity of the voltage was as expected for a diode junction acting as solar cell.

Answer (score 0):

By accident I was able to "fix" my problem. I changed the battery in my multimeter - just to be sure. While measuring once more, I "bumped" the resistor and the LED glowed again. I tried to reproduce the issue again - however strong I bumped the resistor again, nothing happened. LED is glowing now again. Sorry for all the hassle.

I still don't understand, why the voltage was negative.

Comment: This does not answer your question why the voltage was negative. You might want to delete this. Albeit this confirmed the LED being disconnected from the resistor and you were measuring the LED acting as solar cell, converting light hitting it into electricity.